# Skype Alpha - Webcamera

Tags: skype

Is it possible to use webcamera on the new skype alpha version for Linux? If yes, how? Currently only my mic is working

Answer (score 1):

No.

The [Skype FAQ](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34656/more-information-about-skype-for-linux-alpha) says that the feature is in the works, but hasn't been released yet.

You'll have to wait, or hope that Skype for Linux works, which it probably won't.